# HTML5 Localstorage & jQuery: Delete localstorage keys starting with a certain word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have 2 apps working together with localstorage and I was wondering how can I delete all the keys which start with note- and todo- . I know localstorage.clear() clears everything but thats not my aim.

Here is an example of what I have in my localstorage: [image]

Where I want to delete all the todo-* with a button click and all note-* with other button click using jquery.

Thanks alot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138564/looping-through-localstorage-in-html5-and-javascript

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
Object.keys(localStorage)
      .forEach(function(key){
           if (/^todo-|^note-/.test(key)) {
               localStorage.removeItem(key);
           }
       });
```

Comment: it seems to delete the todo-'s only ? Weird

Comment: The RegEx should be `/^(?:todo-|note-)/`. The `?:` will make it a non-capturing group which will speed things up a little. `/^todo-|^note-/` should work too without any grouping at all.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be that the problem. I think the problem is in the coding of that app because I tried to delete the value through firebug and when I refresh I get it the value back.

Answer (score 10):

I used a similar method to @Ghostoy , but I wanted to feed in a parameter, since I call this from several places in my code.  I wasn't able to use my parameter name in a regular expression, so I just used substring instead.

```
function ClearSomeLocalStorage(startsWith) {
    var myLength = startsWith.length;

    Object.keys(localStorage) 
        .forEach(function(key){ 
            if (key.substring(0,myLength) == startsWith) {
                localStorage.removeItem(key); 
            } 
        }); 
}
```