# clearing objects from localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

with localstorage i have a load of unspecified items saved with dynamic names using a data namespace like so:

```
localStorage["myAppName.settings.whatever"] = something.whatever; 

//and this:
localStorage["myAppName.data."+dynObj.name] = dynObj.data;
```

I want to keep the settings but not the data. However I won't ever know what all of the names inside of my data object are so I cannot clear them individually. I need to clear these each time my app is loaded but I must keep the settings so 
`localstorage.clear()` is not an option.

I have tried:

```
localstorage.removeItem("myAppName.data")
```

but no dice.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to clear dynamically named portions of localstorage?

Comment: It's a shame that localStorage doesn't include a namespace as part of the basic API.  In the meantime, there's this: https://github.com/joelarson4/LSNS

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can loop through the keys in the localStorage and target them with a reg exp:

```
Object.keys(localStorage)
      .forEach(function(key){
           if (/^(myAppName.data.)/.test(key)) {
               localStorage.removeItem(key);
           }
       });
```

Here's a similar question: [HTML5 Localstorage & jQuery: Delete localstorage keys starting with a certain word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591893/html5-localstorage-jquery-delete-localstorage-keys-starting-with-a-certain-wo)

Comment: Since `.` matches any character, the regex `myAppName.data.` needs escaping: `myAppName\.data\.`.

Answer (score 2):

try something like

```
var i = localStorage.length, key;
while (i--) {
  key = localStorage.key(i);
  if (key.slice(0, 19) !== "myAppName.settings.") {
    localStorage.remove(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried something like this?

```
// Select current settings
var settings = localStorage["myAppName.settings"] || {};
// Clear localStorage
localStorage.clear();
// Add settings to localStorage
localStorage["myAppName.settings"] = settings;
```

Comment: It should be localStorage.clear(), not localstorage with small s.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a `this.namespace` present (in my case `'session'`) and the underscore library:

```
_.each(_.keys(localStorage), function(key) {
  if (RegExp("^" + this.namespace + "\\.").test(key)) {
    return localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
});
```

And with CoffeeScript:

```
_.each _.keys(localStorage), (key) ->
  if ///^#{@namespace}\.///.test(key)
    localStorage.removeItem(key)
```