# storage.removeItem - how would i use it to remove a multiple items from the value and not the key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, local-storage

I want to be able to delete the value but the not the key from the local storage, any clue?

```
$(".delete").on("click", function() {
    localStorage.removeItem('Property');
});
```

Comment: Set the value to an empty string? (An empty string *is* still a value, but `localStorage` only stores strings.)

Comment: Maybe try to lowercase 'property'

Comment: Check answer of this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591893/html5-localstorage-jquery-delete-localstorage-keys-starting-with-a-certain-wo

Comment: How would your value have multiple items? Are you storing JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [setItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) and set the value as `null` or `blank` like,

```
$(".delete").on("click", function() {
    localStorage.setItem('Property',"");
});
```

**Updated** as per @qutz comment, If you have multiple items then first you need to store values in JSON format then you will be able to parse and  splice to remove a single item like,

```
$(".delete").on("click", function() {
   var ar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Property")),
   item='color';// let we wants to remove color property from json array
   var index = ar.indexOf(item);
   if (index > -1) { // if color property found
       ar.splice(index, 1);// then remove it
   }
   // again set the property without having color
   localStorage.setItem("Property", JSON.stringify(ar));
});
```

Hope this will help you, may be some changes are required as per your logic and method which you've used for it.

Comment: this does somewhat work, i forgot to say i have multiple values

Comment: @qudz - Do you mean multiple *items*? Please update your question to better explain the situation.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I meant to say it has multiple items

Comment: @qudz It is still not easy to understand your problem, but I tried my logic to help you.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue with the solution you have given me, it took a little time but i have managed to get it working. Thanks!