# Is there any difference between: window.localStorage and localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have been doing the following:

```
var store = window.localStorage;
store.setItem()
```

but now I see code doing this:

```
localStorage.setItem()
```

Do both do the same thing?

Comment: `window.` is the "default prefix" so "window.x = x".

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Unless you've declared a variable named `localStorage` in a custom defined scope, they're the same. `localStorage` refers to `window.localStorage`. In fact every variable in global namespace can be accessed as `window.<variableName>`

For example:

```
<script>
function foo() {
    // here window.localStorage == localStorage
}
function foo2() {
    var localStorage = 10;
    // here window.localStorage != localStorage 
    // since you have a local variable named localStorage
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

"window" is the global object in Javascript, so you can ommit it if there's no chance for a conflict

Answer (score 4):

This is old, but today I may have found a difference.

I have a React app that was 'forgetting' the localstorage values when I ran it on my server with SSL without the WI DOW . Without SSL, it was working fine.

I went back and added the WINDOW to all the references to localstorage and the problem disappeared

Answer (score 3):

there is no difference between the  window.localStorage and localStorage the `Window`  is the global object

the window is the default prefix

but  the correct one is `window.localStorage` because the localStorage attribute is part of window object.

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly, window.localStorage makes the localStorage faster to be found than just writing localStorage.

Storing a reference to it on a variable makes it even faster.

Anyway, these improvements are negligible on modern browsers. It only becomes useful if performance is being an issue.
 Anyway, you get a possible idea about why it is being done like that.