# What is more performant, accessing objects from the window or localstorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to store some data in the form of an object and have this data read by a number of components within my React application. For simplicity I'm not using Redux or any other kind of global state management.

Is it more performant to use:

```
const myData = window.myData;
```

Or:

```
const myData = localStorage.getItem('myData');
```

Comment: I bet the `localStorage` method is more expensive (but only by a non-measurably tiny amount), because access requires more nesting. Don't worry about this sort of optimization - instead, consider whether you actually need persistent storage across pageloads (in which case, use localStorage), or if not, use a plain variable (possibly on `window`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between the window.localStorage and localStorage the Window is the global object.

You can find more reading and answers to your question here: [Is there any difference between: window.localStorage and localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660088/is-there-any-difference-between-window-localstorage-and-localstorage)

Here is more reading on why using localStorage directly is harmful: https://michalzalecki.com/why-using-localStorage-directly-is-a-bad-idea/

Im sure you can find what you are looking for, but basically its referring to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

If it's sensitive data in your app context, i would not recommend any of either since your app data would be accessible to others as well.

Instead why not try using [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or try saving data in service object through which you can access it in any component you want.