# If localStorage key is removed, move all next keys by 1 place

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I have this situation where I have `localStorage` keys

```
0,1,2,3
```

and if I delete key `1`, in my loops it breaks when it gets to position `1`, instead of searching for next `2`,`3` etc. So my idea is when I delete one key, for example key `1`, I want all next keys to move up by one place.

I am working with **Angular 1.3**.

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    $scope.stored_data.push(ls.get(i));
 }
```

I am also open for alternative solutions to this problem. As long as I get array with data and loops don't break as they iterate through arrays and `localStorage` it will do.

Comment: Sounds like a `foreach` problem, not a `for` problem.  Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/10768302

Comment: @RobertHarvey but there is a problem. If I for example do this `for (var i in localStorage){
      console.log(i);
    }` the log output is this: `2
1 
0 
key 
getItem 
setItem
removeItem
clear 
length` but I only need keys (0,1,2..) and I want to push their values into array.

Comment: What if you only took the `i`'s that passed [this test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative way to solve your problem. Instead of storing each value separately, try this:

```
//Store a list of the values as an array
var list = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];


//Delete the first value of the array, shifting everything forward
list.shift();

//Since local storage only supports strings, we must stringify the array
localStorage["list"] = JSON.stringify(list);

//When it's time to retrieve the list, parse it back to an array from JSON
list = JSON.parse(localStorage["list"]);
```