# Data is not storing using local Storage ? - Html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I'm trying to get the favorites list using localstorage.

I have a listview with a number of items. When I click on an item it opens up and shows some data.

In the same page I have a button with the text `Bookmark`. When I click on it, that particular page has to be added to that favourites list . When I'm trying to get the list of favourites it shows up empty.

Here is my Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nPwXK/1

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: in while setting the data to localstorage you are using a prefix it is not used when fetching the value back

Comment: you have tons of errors and your `prefix` is undefined

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nPwXK/3/ sorry updated..i'm getting all the list items names along with selected one. but these are not storing in the favorites list.

Comment: @user2384323:It is disgusting to go through your entire code,instead jsut put up some relevant code in your question which you are unsure about!!!that will help

Comment: @TecHunter updated my code with prefix

Comment: @Messiah i think it will gives the clear identification where isthe error is that's why i made a fiddle.

Comment: @user2384323 you should provide relevent code part in your post. fiddle is just a sandbox it's not a post by itself

Comment: ok..@TecHunter i tried your valuable answer but still not storing..

Comment: @user2384323 open the console and look for the errors

Answer (score 0):

Okay so :

- define the `prefix` somewhere.
- localStorage use a Map to store data so when you store something it's a key/value pair.
- Your `indexOf()` is not complete
- you have infinite recursion in `fromStorage()`
- open the console...........!!!

`localStorage.setItem(key, value)`

`localStorage.getItem(key)`

You cannot do `getItem(0)` unless you do `setItem(0)` which you don't.
But you  do this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/nPwXK/11/

You still have some big code readability issue and weird code but it's not the topic here as your localStorage is now working

Comment: btw, I found out this topic with a little search on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138564/looping-through-localstorage-in-html5-and-javascript

Comment: localstorage is working but i have one doubt..here i'm appending to the favorites list why it is not displaying like as in the home page.

Comment: and after adding to favorites list when i close the browser.If i opened again the previous added one's are lost.

Comment: @user2384323 where do you test? I don't think localStorage can work on a framed jsfiddle

Comment: i tested in browser(firefox)..even i tried in fiddle also once it stored..if i closed and opened again nothing is there in favorites list..i tried in fiddle made by you also..its adding unwanted data also.

Comment: @user2384323 like I said. make a real html page not a jsfiddle. your browser won't know how to fetch cache of a dynamic content.

Comment: yes i made a real html page..i tried like index.html and my js file.

Comment: @user2384323 [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FStorage) and you need a web server to test it. Allow cookies too.

Comment: i tried localstorage in the browser and its working but when i click on the particular item in the listview its storing with the last item name but not the clicked one

Comment: @user2384323 your code is messy, you add click event on a class inside a loop that's why you have multiple bookmarks and stuff. Do this step by step, first construct the list then when it's done bind the events, make sure you don't bin them more than once. but it's off topic already. if localstorage is working accept this answer plz.

Comment: but by using your answer data is storing but when closed the browser and opened all the data is losting..its again fresh page

Comment: http://thedevstop.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/getting-started-with-html5-local-storage/

Comment: @TecHunter..Thank u for giving me your valuable suggestion.