# JSON.stringify(localStorage) - filtering by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, filtering

I use a small code snipped to save the localStorage of my application as a string:

`var saveStr = JSON.stringify(localStorage);`

It works great at a first glance, but it basically dump the entire localStorage object, which I don't want. I'd like to stringify the localStorage, but only the keys that contains a certain string.

For instance:
`var saveStr = JSON.stringify(filteredLS("example"));`

**filteredLS** should return the localStorage data, but only the keys that contains the string that was passed as an argument.

Someone knows an easy snipped to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138564/looping-through-localstorage-in-html5-and-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
function filteredLS(term) {
    var filteredObj = {};
    Object.keys(localStorage)

        .filter(function (key) {
            return key.indexOf(term) >= 0;
        })

        .map(function (key) {
            filteredObj[key] = localStorage.getItem(key);
        });

    return JSON.stringify(filteredObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the methods localStorage.getItem and localStorage.setItem. With those, you can write your own get & set functions to easily use JSON objects:

```
function get(item) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(item))
}

function set(item, value) {
    return localStorage.setItem(item, JSON.stringify(value))
}

// use like this:
set('foo', { bar: 1 })
var result = get('foo')
// result: { bar: 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your target browser you may want to transpile this, but for brevity I'm going with a (mostly) es6 style - this should run in modern browsers

Filtering an object by keys:

```
const filterByKeys = obj => keys => Object.entries(obj)
  // keep only the keys we care about
  .filter( ([key, val]) => keys.includes(key) )
  // make a new object with just the filtered keys
  .reduce( (accum, [key, val]) => Object.assign(accum, {[key]:val} ), {} )
```

Usage:

```
// create a function for getting select keys
const localStore = filterByKeys(localStorage)

// call that function with a list of keys you want
const myValues = localStore(['foo', 'bar'])

// and JSON for completeness

const localStoreJson = keys => JSON.stringify(localStore(keys))
```

---

Alternate option if you're transpiling or reading this in the future - using spread operator and compacting filter+reduce into one step - for your purposes this is likely unnecessary:

```
const filterByKeys = obj => keys => Object.entries(obj)
  // filter and reduce in one step
  .reduce( (accum, [key, val]) => keys.includes(key) ? {...accum, [key]:val } : accum, {} )
```