# How do I capture the current value of a variable?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables

I have a big `for` loop (but I have condensed it in a few lines below), and in it I define a few variables, per se like so:

```
for(i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
  var a = localStorage.key(i)
  var b = localStorage.getItem(a)
  cal.addEvent(a, b, '8/7/2020', '8/7/2020')
}
```

In my `addEvent` method, I want to use the CURRENT values of `a` and `b`, but instead it always just gives me the value of `a` and `b` for the last value of `i` in the for loop. How can I get the current values of a and b for the CURRENT value of `i`?

Comment: Don't implicitly create global variables, and always use `const` (or `let`) to declare variables

Comment: @CertainPerformance Another one that could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138564/looping-through-localstorage-in-html5-and-javascript