# How to check the values in sessionStorage in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

How we can check the values in session storage? I mean, if i need to check what are the values stored in Session storage, how we can check that?

Comment: do you know the names of keys for the values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through localStorage in HTML5 and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138564/looping-through-localstorage-in-html5-and-javascript)

Comment: when we don't know the name of key. i want to get all the values in session storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `key` and `value` like this

```
sessionStorage.setItem("user-id", userId);
```

and extract it like this using `key`

```
userId = sessionStorage.getItem("user-id")
```